# Get Sharers with OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm searching for a way to get name of persons who share a specific article with Facebook Graph API.

I'm using `'article_id'/Likes` to get data about persons who like the article, and it work perfectly. But I can't found the solution to find sharers of the article. Is it possible with Graph API?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to retrieves 'sharers' of a specified article, with : `articleID?fields=sharedposts.fields(from)`

Comment: Just test it with developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer : xxxxx(where  xxxxx is the postId)?fields=sharedposts.fields(from)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the Facebook Graph API does not offer this option for the time being.

Comment: Thanks. But bad news :(